# Regular expression for matching a separator and suffix, both optional

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that may contain a separator. This probably means that I have three cases:

```
First and only paragraph
```

---

```
First and only paragraph with redundant separator
<!-- separator -->
```

---

```
First paragraph
<!-- separator -->
Second paragraph
```

I need a regular expression that returns the first and second paragraph (if present) -- separately. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
(.*)(<!-- separator -->.*)  // fails case 1
(.*)(<!-- separator -->.*)? // fails case 2 and 3 (surprise)
```

I just need the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably, that the `.` does not match newline characters by default. You can change this by using the modifier `s`.

```
/(.*)(<!-- separator -->.*)?/s
```

`s` is the single line modifier, it makes the regex treat the input string as "singleline", means the `.` will also match newline characters.

But you should then make the quantifier ungreedy, otherwise the first `.*` will match till the last `<!-- separator -->` in the string.

```
/(.*?)(<!-- separator -->.*)?/s
```

Comment: Something is still missing but I cannot figure out: http://regexr.com?32n0i, http://regexr.com?32n0l and http://regexr.com?32n0o

Comment: @TrueBlue, have you tried it in php? Regexr, is a bit strange, when a regex can also match the empty string, means everything is optional. I tried your examples, maybe the ungreedy version is not perfect (it would match only the last character before the separator), you would need to anchor that to the start of the string/row, by using a `^`.